# Counting time in JavaScript and precision of the results

Tags: javascript, countdown

I decided to use [this](http://www.hashemian.com/tools/javascript-countdown.htm) countdown script, however I noticed that something is wrong.

The site is down right now, but there is [Google Cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3awww.hashemian.com/tools/javascript-countdown.htm%20Code%20can%20be%20find%20here%20http://scripts.hashemian.com/js/countdown.js) for it.
Code can be find [here](http://scripts.hashemian.com/js/countdown.js).

It looks like code is OK, every 1000 milliseconds instructions takes care of changing the output.

But:
I opened page with the script and left it for some hours. After this time I could see "2 hours, 2 minutes". I refreshed the page (it takes 2-3 seconds) and I saw "1 hours, 57 minutes" - is it possible that script is late?

The more time I wait before refresh, the bigger was the diffrence. What can be done to prevent such behaviour of script? What can be done to make it precise?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to have the script make an ajax request every X number of milliseconds. The request would be made to a PHP script that simply responds with the time. The Javascript would then update itself. In other words, you're using the server's current time to adjust the counting of the Javascript.

Comment: Well, I hoped that I could solve this problem with JS. Such amount of PHP requests would kill my hosting.